Observe values of mutableStateOf property - Android ViewModel Unit Testing
I am writing ViewModel unit tests, where the screen state is held in a mutableStateOf property inside the ViewModel. The screen states are two: Loading and Content. How can I track the different states of the mutableStateOf property (and not only the last one), so for example I can make an assertion that the initial state was Loading state.
To be even more clear, if I used MutableLiveData to hold the screen state inside the ViewModel, in order to track the different states I would use the following code:
var viewStates = mutableListOf()
    viewModel.viewState.observeForever {
        viewStates.add(it)
    }

